# How can I count replicate values across columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a fairly simple problem that I need to solve by SQL> 
There is a database that has several columns of values that are duplicate. I am trying to count the number of values that occurs across those columns. I need to know how many values for each category. For example, if there is a column for different types of cookies that one bakery sells; chocolate and raisin and another column has types of cookies that other bakery sells including chocolate and raisin, I want to know how many chocolate cookies all the bakeries sell.

My query:

```
SELECT types_cookies_store01. COUNT(*) FROM cookies
GROUP BY types_cookies_store01
```

This code is returning only one column's count but how can I know the count across all the columns?

Thank you!

Comment: To be of assistance we would need your table layout, some sample data and your desired output.  You are only getting one column because that is all you asked for.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Comment: If my assumptions on your original data is correct add sample data, actual result and expected result to your question (format as table with https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), if not correct my wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data model is poor!

Assuming it is equal to this:

```
| types_cookies_store01 | types_cookies_store02 | types_cookies_store03 |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| A                     |                       |                       |
| C                     |                       |                       |
|                       | A                     |                       |
| A                     |                       |                       |
| B                     |                       |                       |
|                       | B                     |                       |
|                       |                       | B                     |
| C                     |                       |                       |
|                       | C                     |                       |
```

Don't use a new column for each store, use one column to specify the store:

```
| Cookietype | Store |
|------------|-------|
| A          | 01    |
| A          | 03    |
| B          | 02    |
| B          | 01    |
| A          | 02    |
| C          | 02    |
| D          | 02    |
| B          | 03    |
| B          | 01    |
| A          | 03    |
| C          | 03    |
```

Now you can group by Cookietype to get sales of all stores.

```
Select Cookietype, Count(Cookietype) as CountOfCookieType 
From SalesTable 
Group By Cookietype
```

Or to get sales by store add the Store to the group by:

```
Select Cookietype, Store, Count(Cookietype) as CountOfCookieType 
From SalesTable 
Group By Cookietype, Store
```

With that data model you can add (almost) unlimited new stores.

With your data model you need a new column for each new store and tables are limited to 255 columns!

You can work around your poor model, by using a union query:

```
SELECT  UnionCols.Cookietype, COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT types_cookies_store01 As Cookietype, 'Store01' As Store 
    FROM cookies 
    WHERE Not types_cookies_store01 Is Null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT types_cookies_store02 As Cookietype, 'Store02' As Store 
    FROM cookies 
    WHERE Not types_cookies_store02 Is Null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT types_cookies_store03 As Cookietype, 'Store03' As Store 
    FROM cookies 
    WHERE Not types_cookies_store03 Is Null
    ) As UnionCols
Group By UnionCols.Cookietype
```

But performance will be poor on large data and new stores are hard to add.

It is strongly recommended to improve your data model instead of working around it!

Some links to read:

[Database design basics](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/database-design-basics-eb2159cf-1e30-401a-8084-bd4f9c9ca1f5)

[Access All In One](https://www.accessallinone.com/an-in-depth-look-at-data-modelling/)

Comment: Thank you! That is great. If this database is not changeable meaning it is a database that I received and was notified not to update it, do you think I can create a new column on a separate table for the cookietype and stores to specify the stores and connect the databases?

Comment: You can create a new normalized table, but you have to import new data every time (use the UnionCols subquery for that). You will only benefit on that, if you query the data multiple times. Better approach would be to convince the original db creator to provide proper data! Maybe you only get a crosstab query result from a proper data model. If not, don't name that a database as it is most likely only a poor excel sheet ;)